# Delete over rsync using ssh is not working

Tags: rsync

I'm doing an rsync trial where I have two files in the current folder:

```
share_2014_09_08.tar.gz  share_2014_10_08.tar.gz
```

I want to rsync to a remote folder that contains three older files. I use the command:

```
rsync -avz --del ./*.tar.gz backups@pc01:/home/backups/monthly/
```

And the result int the destination folder is:

```
share_2014_03_05.tar.gz  share_2014_09_08.tar.gz  share_2014_10_08.tar.gz
```

As I understand it, this file:

```
share_2014_03_05.tar.gz
```

should have been deleted, so my question is what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing to rsync a list of files that you want to synchronize. Not existing files are not passed, so delete option has no effects.

If you want to delete files, you'll have to synchronize **the parent directory** that contained removed files. You can use a include mask to only sync tarballs:

```
 rsync -avz --include "*.tar.gz" --exclude "*" --del . backups@pc01:/home/backups/monthly/
```